# How to get the prime factors of big number on python?

Tags: python

I want to find largest prime factor of `600851475143`.

But [**`range`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) in my code doesn't work for `600851475143` , too big number .

What should I do? Is there any more efficient algorithm?

```
list=[]
for i in range(1,600851475144):
    count = 0
    if 600851475143 % i == 0:
        for x in range(2,i):
            if i % x == 0:
                count+=1
                print(count)
        if count == 0:
            list.append(i)
        count=0
print(list)
```

Comment: See the [**`continue`**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) keyword to simplify your loop, and use [**`xrange`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead of **`range`**.

Answer (score 1):

This will do :

```
def PrimeFactor(n):
    m = n
    while n%2==0:
        n = n//2
    if n == 1:         # check if only 2 is largest Prime Factor 
        return 2
    i = 3
    sqrt = int(m**(0.5))  # loop till square root of number
    last = 0              # to store last prime Factor i.e. Largest Prime Factor
    while i <= sqrt :
        while n%i == 0:   
            n = n//i       # reduce the number by dividing it by it's Prime Factor
            last = i
        i+=2
    if n> last:            # the remaining number(n) is also Factor of number 
        return n
    else:
        return last
print(PrimeFactor(int(input())))
```

Comment: Thank u so much! It works! But I can't understand why we use sqrt.. Is that a mathematical technique?

Comment: @KYH: why should you check *after* reaching the square root? After that, for all `a*b` results, `a` is going to be larger than `sqrt(target)` and `b` is going to be smaller. But you already checked all possible values for `b` in the first 'half' – as `a`!

Comment: @KYH: to check number is prime or not you check till number's square root  for efficient time so this is also applicable here.. and also as explained by  above comment (by Rad Lexus)